# Content encoding error in a Smarty-based web application

Tags: php, javascript, html, smarty

I have developed a [Smarty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarty_(template_engine))-based web application, but a page is very heavy due to [Google Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) and a lot of HTML code.

It's all about greater than 1 MB at load time. I am trying to *compress* it, because it is updating frequently.

I used:  `.htaccess` configuration for compressing like:

```
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on       Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
```

...but nothing happens.

I also tried the `php gzip` and `ob_start()` method, but it is throwing a content encoding error.  How can I make it possible?

Comment: If you're allowed, a link to the site might help you field better answers.

Comment: »is throwing "Content Encoding Error"« Which doesn't tell us nothing without seeing the code. Also, did you double-checked, that the `mod_gzip` is installed **and** activated in Apache?

Comment: Try using mod_deflate if mod_gzip is not available. No need to also gzip in php if you use apache's deflate.

Answer (score 3):

1. We have some problems of the encoding procedure. Sometimes we miss for the encoding command. If we follow the real procedure (command) or encoding software, then our problem may be solved in this case.

   As an example, we want to make a .gzip file:

   ```
   gzip -9 production.min.css
   ```

   It will make the *production.min.css.gz* file.
2. Sometimes it may occur, if your configuration to pick data from various server as [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) and others. The solution is to turn on `zlib.output_compression` in your `php.ini`.

   Open your `php.ini`. On **Debian/Ubuntu**, it's `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`:

   ```
   vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
   ```

   On [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29), [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS), and [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux), it's */etc/php.ini*:

   ```
   vi /etc/php.ini
   ```

   Find the `zlib.output_compression` line and turn `zlib.output_compression` on:

   ```
   zlib.output_compression = On
   ```

   Restart Apache afterwards:

   On Debian and Ubuntu, you run:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

   On Fedora/CentOS/RedHat, you run:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/httpd restart
   ```
3. Clear your browser cache, cookies, etc. just to be sure.

   It most likely will not fix the problem permanently or even temporarily.
4. It could be an issue with gzip.

   Open a new tab and enter the following `"about:config"`, and then you'll see a warning to be careful. Just confirm it.

   In the search bar, enter `"network.http.accept-encoding"`.
   Make sure its value is `gzip, deflate`. If not, right click it and click the option to reset.

   Some people report changing it to `"true"`. It can fix the problem, but I would not recommend it since it's most likely going to cause more problems down the road.
5. Check your firewall especially if you're using [ZoneAlarm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZoneAlarm).
   Removing all the added programs and resetting the defaults actually fixed it the first time for me.
6. Clear your *SSL slate* by going into your control panel then clicking Internet options.

   Once open, click the *Content* tab and click *Clear SSL slate*.
7. Are you using a custom DNS? I.e., [OpenNIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenNIC). If so, turn it off to make sure. If you don't know what I'm talking about, ignore this.
8. Run a good privacy cleaning program like [Advanced SystemCare](https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_SystemCare) or whatever you use to do that.

   The last time it happened to me, I did all of the following followed by a `reboot`.

   I've not had the issue again in any browser and it's been a good while now.